# dataframe apply function taking more than 24 hours to execute

Tags: python, regex, function, dataframe, apply

```
def city_check(test):
    test=str(test)
    for ele in city:    #city is a list containing 2200 city names.
        ele=str(ele)
        
        result = re.findall('\\b'+ele+'\\b', test, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        if len(result)>0:
            return ele
    return "Not Found"

df['city']=df['address_line_1'].apply(city_check) #df has 2.5 million rows
```

Why does it take so long and how can I make it faster?

Comment: please suggest a edit or alternate code so as to execute it faster , thanks.

Comment: Can you post a running example, please. It may contain much less data. Like only 2 or 3 elements in city and df

Comment: How does such a row in df look like?

Comment: df has 3 columns namely , job_id (int), address_line_1 ( varchar(300)), city(varchar and blank) .

Comment: and how does this varcahr(300) look like? How likely is it to find a result in re.findall?

Comment: 93346 INDIA BULLS 2ND FLOOR GARND MALL GT ROAD JAL... 1   None None
5 93346 U WB FAIRLAND COLONY FGC ROAD JALANDHAR PUNJAB 1   None None
6 129128 D 501 WHESPERING PALMS XCLUSIVE AKURLI ROAD LO... 1   None None
7 62321 GUT NO: BUILDING NAME: BUILDING NO 130 HOUSE N... 1   None None
8 147383 D NO 20 1 272 RAMALAYAM STREET MANGALAM ROAD T... 1   None None

Comment: there should be matches in 20 rows out of 100 rows.

Comment: i just need the first match to be returned via function

Comment: Something like this? `df['city'] = df['address_line_1'].lower().apply(lambda x: [item for item in str(x).split() if item in city])`

Comment: @Ale '"abc" in string.spit()' takes longer than '" abc " in string'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only require the first match to be returned via a function, I suggest using `re.search` or `re.match` for this regex operation. `re.findall` is fairly costly in terms of processing power, especially considering the large amount of rows you are processing.

Details on the different regex functions: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Further improvements to the speed of this operation could probably be achieved through utilising a multiprocessing module like `multiprocessing`. Documentation [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

However, this would depend on how often you need this function ran and whether its worth the development time!

Comment: daniel , can u give me the code for using multiprocessing in this dataframe scenario.  I am a bit new , will be quite helpful. Thanks.

Comment: He don't use the result from regex, he just returns another value, so regex isn't needed at all here and just wastes time because this is regex is made for more complicated things

Comment: Oh yeah jjj thats very true!

Comment: Pankit, jjj's answer will reduce your processing time dramatically and doesnt require you to do anything fancy! See what his method does to your processing time. But test the performance of new vs old method on a small set of data to not waste alot of your time!

Comment: Daniel i need regex for getting exact match , a sub is providing wrong results sometimes like del can be matched with deli which is not expected , so i used regex with boundaries added.

Comment: @pankitGujjar thats no problem, you can just add spaces at the beginning and end for the name, when creating the list

Answer (score 1):

Why does it take so long?:

You call the function on all 2.5 million entries. Every time you do this, you loop over 2500 cities (early returns are rare, so I ignored them). So you call the `re.findall()` 2 500 000*2 500 = 5 500 000 000 times.

To just add +1 100 million times, it took my laptop around 7s. That would be over 6 minuets for 5.5 billion times and I only tested one of the fastest operations and you use much more complicated operations.

How can it be faster?:

Most of you time is used by the regex function.
You don't need regex here, you can use `"sub" in "string"`, that is much faster (in a small test I just made it was around 15 times faster.

```
if city.lower() in test.lower(): # in reply to some comments: yes that can lead to wrong results, but keep reading
    ...
```

You can optimize more by not calling `.lower()` every time. Before you do `.apply()`, create a list of all city names in lower case (and add surroundings like spaces to the beginning and end of each city name to fix the wrong result problem), so you only have to do this once and convert `test` to lower case at the start of the function.

```
def city_check(test):
    test=str(test).lower()
    for ele in cityLowerNames:
        if ele in test:
            return ele
    return "Not Found"
```

As further optimization you can run the loop in parallel, but since you loop over only 2500 items, it would not be that effective, or maybe worse, when you start additional threads every time. So if you try to do it in parallel, make sure, you start the threads once and keep them running. Maybe you can get like 4 times faster with that, depends on how many additional logic is needed.

Comment: this wont work as expected sir , e.g. pala in city will be matched with palam in address. i want the exact match, so used regex with boundaries added. sub is giving wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'address_line_1': ['93346 INDIA BULLS 2ND FLOOR GARND MALL GT ROAD JAL... 1', 'None', 'None', '5 93346 U WB FAIRLAND COLONY FGC ROAD JALANDHAR PUNJAB 1', 'None', 'None', '6 129128 D 501 WHESPERING PALMS XCLUSIVE AKURLI ROAD LO... 1', 'None', 'None', '7 62321 GUT NO: BUILDING NAME: BUILDING NO 130 HOUSE N...1', 'None', 'None', '8 147383 D NO 20 1 272 RAMALAYAM STREET MANGALAM ROAD']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

city=list(['akurli','ramalayam'])

df['city'] = df['address_line_1'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in str(x).lower().split() if item in city])
df['city'] = df['city'].str[0]
df
```

And I got

```
    address_line_1                                      city
0   93346 INDIA BULLS 2ND FLOOR GARND MALL GT ROAD...   NaN
1   None                                                NaN
2   None                                                NaN
3   5 93346 U WB FAIRLAND COLONY FGC ROAD JALANDHA...   NaN
4   None                                                NaN
5   None                                                NaN
6   6 129128 D 501 WHESPERING PALMS XCLUSIVE AKURL...   akurli
7   None                                                NaN
8   None                                                NaN
9   7 62321 GUT NO: BUILDING NAME: BUILDING NO 130...   NaN
10  None                                                NaN
11  None                                                NaN
12  8 147383 D NO 20 1 272 RAMALAYAM STREET MANGAL...   ramalayam
```

Now, probably it's not the most efficient way but I could replicate it on a large df pretty fast:

```
dff = pd.concat([df]*1000000, ignore_index=True)
dff.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 13000000 entries, 0 to 12999999
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column          Dtype 
---  ------          ----- 
 0   address_line_1  object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 99.2+ MB

%%time
dff['city'] = dff['address_line_1'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in str(x).lower().split() if item in city])

CPU times: user 19.7 s, sys: 856 ms, total: 20.5 s
Wall time: 20.5 s
```